# Should the implementation guard itself against comma overloading?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, comma-operator

For example `uninitialized_copy` is defined in the standard as:

> *Effects:*
>
> ```
> for (; first != last; ++result, ++first)
>   ::new (static_cast<void*>(&*result))
>     typename iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type(*first);
> ```

If understood literally, this is a requirement to call `operator ,(ForwardIterator, InputIterator)`. And in fact this code prints `Hello world!` ten times:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
 
using namespace std;

namespace N {     
    struct X : iterator<forward_iterator_tag, int> {
        pointer _p;
        X(pointer p) : _p(p) {}
        X& operator++() { ++_p; return *this; }
        X operator++(int) { X r(*this); ++_p; return r; }
        reference operator*() const { return *_p; }
        pointer operator->() const { return _p; }
    };
     
    bool operator==(X a, X b) { return a._p == b._p; }
    bool operator!=(X a, X b) { return !(a == b); }
     
    void operator,(X a, X b) { cout << "Hello world!\n"; }
}

int a[10], b[10];
 
int main()
{
    using N::X;
    uninitialized_copy(X(a), X(a+10), X(b));
}
```

However, for most other algorithms the standard gives the description in prose. E.g. for `copy` there's no requirement for operator `,` to be called. But if I change

```
    uninitialized_copy(X(a), X(a+10), X(b));
```

in the above code to

```
    copy(X(a), X(a+10), X(b));
```

then `Hello world!` is *still printed ten times*. The said results are observable in both, VS2005 and GCC 4.3.4. However, if I write

```
    mismatch(X(a), X(a+10), X(b));
```

instead, then VS2005 prints `Hello world!` ten times but GCC does not.

Unfortunately I couldn't find where the standard prohibits `operator,` overloading for iterator types. On the contrary, it prohibits the implementations to do calls as above [global.functions]:

> Unless otherwise specified, global and non-member functions in the standard library shall not use functions from another namespace which are found through argument-dependent name lookup (3.4.2).

So who of the four parties is wrong: MSVC, GCC, ISO or me? (Choose one)

Comment: I think Visual C++, gcc, and ISO are all wrong:  Visual C++ and gcc should not be using the comma operator, and the spec (ISO) should not use the comma in its example code.  I could be wrong; that's just my first thought on the matter.  (Please consider opening a Visual C++ bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio); it's at least worth bringing to their attention.)

Comment: Given that even something like `Size` is a templated type, I'd turn the argument on its head and say that the standard wants *precisely* what it says, and if you see reason to provide a custom comma operator, then you are invited to do so, and you will get the specified behaviour.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis KerrekSB: Thank you. I hope someone can find a place where it's said to be undefined behavior, otherwise we have three bug reports to open.

Comment: @ybungalobill: FYI you can't notify two people in one comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nice catch. I think in my humble opinion that the ISO committee's intention was that §3.4.2 should be followed. The suggested semantics of `uninitialized_copy` is wrongly interpreted as if requiring the comma to be called. And implementations should not be using it (I'd report a bug to gcc btw).

Comment: This is my interpretation as well. Comma overloading is crazy and I think it just slipped past our commitee members' attention.

Comment: Yeah, since then I submitted a PR and AFAIK they fixed the standard and the popular implementations followed removing the unintended comma operator calls.